# How can I digitally recreating water sounds

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, noise, foley, digital

I need a digitally created water sound, that is convincing enough but also not too realistic sounding. I have good ableton live and a bit MaxMSP knowledge but i don't know how to design this specific sound. can someone give me a tip?

thanks!

Comment: What kind of 'water sound'? The ocean, a stream, waterfall, rain, a tap running in a sink...

Answer (score 1):

Andy Farnell's Pure Data patches sure will help you a lot!

It would be nice if you specified the kind of water sounds...
Anyway, here you probably have most flavours you want:

[Water bubbles](http://mitpress2.mit.edu/designingsound/bubbles.asp)
[Running water](http://mitpress2.mit.edu/designingsound/water.asp)
[Pouring water](http://mitpress2.mit.edu/designingsound/pouring.asp)
[Rain](http://mitpress2.mit.edu/designingsound/rain.asp)

Go and get them :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone made a semi-convincing wave-sound with Pd :

. The patch is certainly quite straightforward to reproduce in MaxMSP.